# GCP, RabbitMQ click-to-deploy service, how to disable Stack Driver metrics exporter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rabbitmq

I've created a RabbitMQ kubernetes cluster using Google One Click to deploy. I've checked "Enable Stackdriver Metrics Exporter" and created the cluster. My problem is that Google is charging for every custom metric created. 
I need to disable Stackdriver Metrics Exporter. 
¿Anyone had the same issue and disabled this Exporter? If so ¿How can I disable it without destroying the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

If this kubernetes cluster without another application, only RabbitMQ is running on it, you can disable “Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring” function of kubernetes cluster.

In the Cloud Console, go to the Kubernetes Engine > [Kubernetes clusters page](https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/list?_ga=2.189796781.-709885236.1578004034):
Click your cluster.
Click Edit for the cluster you want to change.
Set the “Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring” drop-down value to Disabled.
Click Save.

[The Logs ingestion page](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#stop-logs) in the Logs Viewer tracks the volume of logs in your project. The Logs Viewer also gives you tools to disable all logs ingestion or exclude (discard) log entries you're not interested in, so that you can minimize any charges for logs over your monthly allotment.

[Go to logs exports](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/exports?_ga=2.197089962.-709885236.1578004034), and follow this [topic](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#deleting_sinks) for manage "Logs Exports".